# JSON object but can't parse

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I need to do a lookup onto an itunes url which throws the json, in my nodejs based backend, i am using requests module of nodejs to get the json, and it indeed returns me the json as well, but the moment i try parsing it doesn't return me internal objects, however calls like stringify or JSON.parse just work without any exception.
sample url https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=477091027

```
//sample url https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=477091027
 request(itunesUrl, function (error, response, body) {
                      if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {         
                        var jsonbody = JSON.stringify(body.trim());                                                                        
                        var obj = JSON.parse(jsonbody);            
                        console.log(obj);                          
                        /*for(var myKey in obj) 
                        {
                           console.log("key:"+myKey+", value:"+obj[myKey]);
                       }*/

                        //none of these show value in them
                        appinfo.appname = obj.results[0].trackName;
                        appinfo.appImage = obj.results[0].artworkUrl60;
                        appinfo.appCategory = obj.results[0].genres[0];
                      }
                    });
```

I am at my wits end now

Comment: Why should `appinfo.appname = obj.results[0].trackName;` **show** anything? It just assigns it to a variable.

Comment: Rremove `var jsonbody = JSON.stringify(body.trim());` and use `var obj = JSON.parse(body);`. The response is already JSON. You don't want to convert a string containing JSON *to* JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you are `stringify`ing the json before `parse`-ing it again :

```
var jsonbody = JSON.stringify(body.trim());                                                                        
var obj = JSON.parse(jsonbody);
```

If `body` is supposed to contain json, then you directly should do

```
var obj = JSON.parse(body);
```

Comment: right you are, and i tried that first, but it won't work

Comment: *"but it won't work"* If you elaborate on that, we might be able to help you. If not....then not.

Comment: perfect, lets close this question, a stupid very stupid very very stupid mistake at my end, i shouldn't have posted .... (facepalm)

Comment: I voted myself for "close" this shouldn't even be here on such pious platform .......

Answer (score 1):

you just need to add the parameter `json:true`

```
request({url:itunesUrl, json:true}, function (error, response, body) {
                      if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                       console.log(body.results[0].trackName)


                        }
                    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though Ninetainedo's answer looks correct, the docs suggest that you can use `json: true` as a parameter in the request options. This will automatically parse the json into a object, removing the need for the `JSON.parse()` line.

See https://github.com/request/request#requestoptions-callback

Comment: my bad man, it was a mistake at my end, typo and stuff.... lets close this question.